# Heap corruption when shared_ptr is destroyed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Considering the following example code:

Uncopyable.h

```cpp
class Uncopyable {
protected:
    Uncopyable() {}
    ~Uncopyable() {}

private:
    Uncopyable(const Uncopyable&);
        Uncopyable& operator=(const Uncopyable&);
};
```

Base.h

```cpp
class Base : private Uncopyable
{
public:
    Base(int a);

    virtual ~Base();

private:
    int mValBase;
};
```

Base.cpp

```cpp
Base::Base(int a)
    : mValBase(a)
{
}

Base::~Base()
{
}
```

Derived.h

```cpp
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int a, int b);

    ~Derived();

private:
    int mValDerived;
};
```

Derived.cpp

```cpp
Derived::Derived(int a, int b)
    : Base(a),
      mValDerived(b)
{
}

Derived::~Derived()
{
}
```

When I insert the following code block (not all code shown here)

```cpp
{
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> derived = std::shared_ptr<Derived>(new Derived(1, 2));
}
```

I get a heap corruption ("CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer") upon exit of the code block and destruction of the shared_ptr `derived`. However, if I remove the initialization of `mValDerived` in the constructor of `Derived` I get no heap corruption. Also, if I insert the above classes and code in a very short console application I get no heap corruption.

Can anyone help me understand what the problem is and how fix it? I am at a loss.

I am using VS2012.

Comment: virtual ~Uncopyable() {} ?

Comment: @Eugene Unless he's holding pointers of `Uncopyable*` static type -- which would be a weird thing to do -- there's no need for a virtual destructor there. Compare `boost::noncopyable`, which similarly has a non-virtual destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the code. If it works in a short console program the error is probably in some other part of you program. You will have to systematically check other parts of your program until the error goes away.

Comment: thanks for confirming that there was nothing wrong with the code. I kept modifying and analyzing the classes above because that's where the debugger told me something was wrong, even though I also could see nothing wrong with the code, and it was driving me nuts. After having removed piece after piece of the other code in the program I was able to locate the problem: In a struct definition I redefined the packing alignment with `#pragma pack` without "popping" it back to the previous packing mode afterwards. This broke packing alignment required by the the code that followed.